# Poincare Map for $\dot{x}=-x(t)+\sin(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Im looking at the equation $\dot{x}=-x(t)+\sin(t)$ and am trying to derive a formula form for the Poincare map corresponding to the Poincare section $\{(x,t):  t=2\pi\}$.  I know that if I solve my equation I get

$$x(t)=\frac{1}{2}(\sin(t)-\cos(t)+2c/e^t)$$

Next I know that $x(0)=x(2\pi)$ and so

$$x(t)=\frac{1}{2}(\sin(t)-\cos(t))$$

Thus the poincare map starts at $F(x_0)=x(2\pi)=-\frac{1}{2}$.  I'm not quit sure how to find the Poincare map, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know $x(t)=\frac12(\sin(t)-\cos(t)+2Ce^{-t})$. If $x(0)=x_0$, we have $C-\frac{1}{2}=x_0$, and $C=x_0+\frac12$. Thus we have the flow $x(t,x_0)=\frac12\left(\sin(t)-\cos(t)+\left(2x_0+1\right)e^{-t}\right)$. The Poincare map is $$P(x_0)=x(2\pi,x_0)=-\frac{1}{2}+\left(x_0+\frac{1}{2}\right)e^{-2\pi}.$$

You can also see that $x_0=-1/2$ is a fixed point of the Poincare map, which confirms the periodic orbit you found.